# Pulling certain tokens in for /f in batch file

Tags: batch-file

OK, I'm new to here and new to batch scripting, but I am starting to get the hang of it.

This is what I am trying to do.  I have a file that contains a line that I pulled from another file and is tab separated.  The line looks like this:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 COL6
Date name ID   Cost dept site
```

What I am trying to do is pull just certain tokens out to set some text files.  But I am having issues with handling blank tokens/columns, and some of the columns have spaces in them.  This is the code that I have, but it does not return what I am looking for

```
SET datalocation=mydatalocation
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,4,6" %%a in (%datalocation%\filename.txt) do (
    echo %%a > %datalocation%\col1.txt
    echo %%b > %datalocation%\col4.txt
    echo %%c > %datalocation%\col6.txt
    )
```

The output I am getting is a mess.  COL1.txt will have half of col1 and all of col2 in it.  Col4.txt and Col6.txt both state echo is off, so I assume the variable returned was blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

attaching sample data

Last Connect    Device ID   Operating System    OS Level    Serial Num  MAC Address Primary UserID  Primary First Name  Primary Last Name   Primary Expense Code    Billed UID  Billed First Name   Billed Last Name    Billed Expense Code
12/10/2013 8:16 Mycomputer  Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Version 6.1.7601 [Build 7601]    Service Pack 1  1234abc 4437e6a3e5d5    JasonM  Jason   Moseley CB0000012345    JasonM  Jason   Moseley CB0000012345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up finally using for my code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR /F "delims=" %%L in (%sourcedir%\filename.csv) DO (
        set "line=%%L,"

    set "line=#!line:,=,#!"

    FOR /F "tokens=7,8,9,11 delims=," %%a in ("!line!") DO (
        IF NOT "%%~a"=="" ECHO(%%~a >>"%sourcedir%\col01.txt"
        IF NOT "%%~b"=="" ECHO(%%~b >>"%sourcedir%\col02.txt"
        IF NOT "%%~c"=="" ECHO(%%~c >>"%sourcedir%\col03.txt"
        IF NOT "%%~d"=="" ECHO(%%~d >>"%sourcedir%\col04.txt"
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
goto final
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "tab=   "
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1,2,4delims=%tab%" %%a IN (%sourcedir%\q20574891.txt
 ) DO (
  ECHO(%%a >>"%sourcedir%\col1.txt"
  ECHO(%%b >>"%sourcedir%\col2.txt"
  ECHO(%%c >>"%sourcedir%\col4.txt"
)
ENDLOCAL
:: Environment is now cleared of changes
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (%sourcedir%\q20574891.txt) DO SET "tab=%%a"&GOTO tabset
:tabset
SET tab=%tab:*Col 1=%
SET tab=%tab:~0,1%
ECHO tab=+%tab%+ >u:\junk.txt
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1,2,4delims=%tab%" %%a IN (%sourcedir%\q20574891.txt
 ) DO (
  ECHO(%%a >>"%sourcedir%\col1.txt"
  ECHO(%%b >>"%sourcedir%\col2.txt"
  ECHO(%%c >>"%sourcedir%\col4.txt"
)
ENDLOCAL
:: Environment is now cleared of changes
:final
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (%sourcedir%\q20574891.txt) DO SET "tab=%%a"&GOTO tabset
:tabset
:: Need to change the string between * and = on next line to column 1's name
SET tab=%tab:*Last Connect=%
SET tab=%tab:~0,1%
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%w IN (%sourcedir%\q20574891.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%w"
 SET "line="!line:%tab%="%tab%"!""
 FOR /f "tokens=1-15delims=%tab%" %%a IN ("!line!"
  ) DO (
   IF NOT "%%~a"=="" ECHO(%%~a >>"%sourcedir%\col01.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~b"=="" ECHO(%%~b >>"%sourcedir%\col02.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~c"=="" ECHO(%%~c >>"%sourcedir%\col03.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~d"=="" ECHO(%%~d >>"%sourcedir%\col04.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~e"=="" ECHO(%%~e >>"%sourcedir%\col05.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~f"=="" ECHO(%%~f >>"%sourcedir%\col06.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~g"=="" ECHO(%%~g >>"%sourcedir%\col07.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~h"=="" ECHO(%%~h >>"%sourcedir%\col08.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~i"=="" ECHO(%%~i >>"%sourcedir%\col09.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~j"=="" ECHO(%%~j >>"%sourcedir%\col10.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~k"=="" ECHO(%%~k >>"%sourcedir%\col11.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~l"=="" ECHO(%%~l >>"%sourcedir%\col12.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~m"=="" ECHO(%%~m >>"%sourcedir%\col13.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~n"=="" ECHO(%%~n >>"%sourcedir%\col14.txt"
   IF NOT "%%~o"=="" ECHO(%%~o >>"%sourcedir%\col15.txt"
 )
```

)
    ENDLOCAL

```
GOTO :EOF
```

Really need to know a little more about your data.  Above is two ways - the first assumes that you can actually insert a real, live <kbd>Tab</kbd> into your source. The second derives the `tab` from the data file but relies on your knowing the header of column 1 (`Col 1` in my testing)

Next problem - and one I haven't approached is that `FOR/F` treats a series of delimiters as a single delimiter, so if the data contains

<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

then extra processing will be required, whereas

<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

will be safe.

OK - edited to deal with sequences of tabs. Astonished that I used the same technique as dbenham - even the same temporary-dataname `line`

I've added an improvement so that `col2` will not receive empty lines for an empty column, and my column numbers are different for testing purposes - lack of sample data :(

Ah - adjusted again. Most of the demo solution is now skipped over - I'll leave it there for the sake of any who may be interested.

You'd need to change the column name in the indicated position to match column 1's name. There's no way that any process can determine with certainty what the column-delimiter is. I simply used "Col 1" as a test-data column-name in the absence of test data.

**Alternatively** and probably preferably, you could set the variable `tab` to a real, live <kbd>Tab</kbd> - a little difficult to show here. The syntax is shown in the fifth line of the above code - the quotes ensure that trailing spaces are **NOT** included in the value assigned.

Comment: +1, I addressed consecutive delimiters in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20585406/1012053)

Comment: That seems to be my problem.  Sometimes the data has TAB TAB in it so it is being processed as one delimiter. 

more information about the data
col1 has date and time stamp from when the data was pulled
col2 has Computer name
col3 has operating system
col4 has service pack level
col5 has username

Comment: I wasnt sure how to attach a sample file so i did not include it before.  I have edited above with a sample of the data that I am using.  When using the new modified code I still get a jumbled output.  Hoping the sample data with give some light as to what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  I could not get your code to work which I suspect has something to do with my data file.  I was able to get it to work by reformatting my data file to csv instead of tab delimited.  used code very similar to yours Magoo and Dbenham for handling the repeating delimiters.  I will post by code later today

Answer (score 2):

The code below will properly handle missing values (consecutive tab delimiters) by enclosing all values in quotes first.

The default DELIMS option is tab and space, so you must explicitly set DELIMS to a tab if a value may contain spaces.

The code below that defines tab should have a tab character hard coded in the script

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define a TAB character (hard coded tab - not spaces)
set "tab=   "

:: Read entire line without parsing tokens
set "datalocation=mydatalocation"
for /f usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%datalocation%\filename.txt") do set "line=%%L"

:: Put quotes around all token values:  <tab>B<tab>C   becomes   ""<tab>"B"<tab>"C"
set "line="!line:%tab%="%tab%"!""

:: Parse the values. Use `~` to remove enclosing quotes.
:: Enclose ECHO statement in parentheses to prevent unwanted trailing space in output
:: Use ECHO( to prevent ECHO is off message if value is empty
for /f "eol=%tab% delims=%tab% tokens=1,4,6" %%A in ("!line!") do (
  (echo(%%~A) >"%datalocation%\col1.txt"
  (echo(%%~B) >"%datalocation%\col4.txt"
  (echo(%%~C) >"%datalocation%\col6.txt"
)
```

Comment: This code did not seem to work for me.  It just returned my entire line as the first output

Comment: @Hellobum - I tested, and it works fine for me. I'm assuming you have only one data line, since your are writing to the output files using over-write mode. Therefore your output files can only have data from the last line processed. If you want data from multiple lines, then you need to use `>>`, and my code needs to change a bit.

Comment: there is only one line of data that is needed, but when i run the code all I get is the full line of original data in the first txt file col1.txt.  It must be something with the way my data is formated in the file.

Comment: @Hellobum - Hmmm, Are you sure you have defined the TAB variable correctly to contain an actual tab character? Other than that, I don't know what else to suggest.